# Unable to login to meta (using my laptop)

Tags: support, user-accounts

It has been an issue *(with my account?)* since a past few months. I registered myself in **meta.stackexchange.com** a few months back. Since then I have not been able to access my **meta.math.stackexchange.com** account in my laptop. *(I am using windows 7 and Chrome)*, though I can access it using my phone *(and because of this, I don't intend to logout my account from the phone)*.

When I open my profile page at SE and click on *meta user*, I am directed to my profile page of Meta MSE *(as it'd be shown to another user)* and I am unable to login.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any suggestions? **I have tried switching browsers, and it hasn't worked**. Thank you.

Comment: This _might_ be an issue with an extension you are using. A possibly similar issue [was reported on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238471/214632), with the outcome that a specific Chrome extension (in that case [Power Switch](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/powerswitch/lljbpnomhjlnohbcipjjjmnbncfofobe)) was to blame.

Comment: Yes, that actually helped. `https everywhere` wasn't allowing the device to login to the account as a secure connection wasn't established. Thank you. Please post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was caused by a **Chrome Extension** ([HTTPS Everywhere](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)) interfering with the request to log in, as a secure connection could not be established. *(Well, if you are a politician surrounded by security guards, you wouldn't be able to reach out to the general public that easily, isn't it?)*

As @`Arthur Fischer` notified in the comments, a similar issue has been reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238471/214632) and there was again an Extension, [Power Switch](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/powerswitch/lljbpnomhjlnohbcipjjjmnbncfofobe) which was found interfering with the normal working.

Comment: I can say that extension on Linux hasn't posed a problem with Firefox.